# How can I fix this Bash function to start at a specified path and recursively list its subdirectories and the subdirectories of those etc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to write a script that searches a directory and it's subdirectories etc for files matching a given regular expression. So I have started by attempting to write a function to get the directories and subdirectories first. For some reason it currently only seems to get the first subdirectory in the specified directory.

Here is the function:

```
getDirs() {

cd "$1"
for i in *; do
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        echo "dir: $PWD/$i"
        getDirs "$i"
    fi
done
}

getDirs $path
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, although `find` is more efficient.

```
getDirs() {
    for i in "$1"/*; do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
            echo "$i"
            getDirs "$i"
        fi
    done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this using [find](/questions/tagged/find) if you need a *regex* for searching file names :

```
regex="YourRegexPattern"
find "$1" -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex "$regex"
```

if you want to get all dirs/subdirs :

```
find . -type d
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's only because you never go back to the previous directory after your loop. You could put everything in a subshell thus:

```
getDirs() {
    (
    cd "$1"
    for i in *; do
        if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then
            echo "dir: $PWD/$i"
            getDirs "$i"
        fi
    done
    )
}

getDirs $path
```

or save the current dir to `cd` to it after your loop thus:

```
getDirs() {
    local currentdir=$PWD
    cd "$1"
    for i in *; do
        if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then
            echo "dir: $PWD/$i"
            getDirs "$i"
        fi
    done
    cd "$currentdir"
}

getDirs $path
```

or other... I guess you now see where your mistake was!

You should also check that your `cd` worked with, e.g., `cd "$1" || <do something as the cd failed>`.